# Setting width as percentage inside a vertical or horizontal layout view

Tags: ios, user-interface, titanium

I am just newbie in Titanium development so sorry if it is a fools question... I have been reading the docs but I haven't found what I am looking for so here I go,

I am trying to set the width of a view as percentage -**labelDetails** in code below-. That view is nested inside a tableViewRow with layout horizontal (or vertical, it doesn't matter)- **row** in code below-. I use something like:

```
function randomInt(max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
}

tableData = []; //Tabla de Rows
for (var i=1; i<=20; i++){
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        className:'forumEvent', 
        backgroundColor:'green',
        rowIndex:i, 
        height:110,
        width:'100%',
        layout:'horizontal'
    });



    var labelUserName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'#576996',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        font:{fontFamily:'Arial', fontWeight:'bold'},
        text:'Fred Smith ' + i,
        left:70, top: 6,
        width:200, height: 30
    });
    row.add(labelUserName);

    var labelDetails = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color:'#222',
        font:{fontFamily:'Arial', fontWeight:'normal'},
        text:'Replied to post with id ' + randomInt(1000) + '.',
        left:70, top:44,
        width: '50%', //Here is the percentage
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    });
    row.add(labelDetails);



  tableData.push(row);
}


var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    data:tableData
});

self.add(tableView);
```

~~~

When I run the emulator, labelDetails is not shown. If I change labelDetails' width to px or just default units, everything works as expected.

My system:

- Application type: mobile
- Titanium SDK: 3.0.
- Platform & version: iOS 6.0
- Device: iOS simulator
- Host Operating System: OSX 10.8.2
- Titanium Studio: 3.0.1.201212181159

Is this a bug? What is the proper way to go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you ever set the width of the tableView.  If the tableView has a "0" width, its cells with 100% width will still have a 0 width.

Try setting the width of your tableView.

Comment: That didn't resolve my issue. Views fill their parent width by default. Thanks anyway Brandon. Any other proposal?